# QUERY AND DROPDOWN FILTER FORMULA IN GOOGLE SHEET

Tags: google-sheets

I am sharing the google sheet file that I prepared. Can you fix everything wrong with it? I am deaf. Please help to make the sheet correct.

[text](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1B6Yab4i6BXaSXYKulC3b4qIKAQSj3968frrQRamTAMY/edit?usp=sharing)

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1B6Yab4i6BXaSXYKulC3b4qIKAQSj3968frrQRamTAMY/edit?usp=sharing

my gogle sheet code

```
=IF(A2="ALL WARD LICENSE APPLICATIONS", 
  QUERY(ALL!B3:K,"SELECT * "),
 IF(A2="WARD 1 LICENSE APPLICATIONS", 
    QUERY(ALL!B3:K, 
          "SELECT * WHERE D CONTAINS 'MP 01/' "),
 IF(A2="WARD 2 LICENSE APPLICATIONS", 
    QUERY(ALL!B3:K, 
          "SELECT * WHERE D CONTAINS 'MP 02/' "),
 IF(A2="WARD 3 LICENSE APPLICATIONS", 
    QUERY(ALL!B3:K, 
          "SELECT * WHERE D CONTAINS 'MP 03/' "),
 IF(A2="WARD 4 LICENSE APPLICATIONS", 
    QUERY(ALL!B3:K, 
          "SELECT * WHERE D CONTAINS 'MP 04/' "),
 IF(A2="WARD 5 LICENSE APPLICATIONS", 
    QUERY(ALL!B3:K, 
          "SELECT * WHERE D CONTAINS 'MP 05/' "),
 IF(A2="WARD 6 LICENSE APPLICATIONS", 
    QUERY(ALL!B3:K, 
          "SELECT * WHERE D CONTAINS 'MP 06/' "),



=IF(A3="ALL APPLICATIONS", 
  QUERY(ALL!B3:K,"SELECT * "),

 IF(A3="ALL NEW LICENSE APPLICATIONS", 
    QUERY(ALL!B3:K, 
          "SELECT * WHERE H CONTAINS 'NEW LICENSE APPLICATION' "),

IF(A3="ALL RENEWAL LICENSE APPLICATIONS", 
      QUERY(ALL!B3:K, 
            "SELECT * WHERE H CONTAINS 'RENEWAL LICENSE APPLICATIONS' "),

IF(A3="FEE NOT PAIND", 
      QUERY(ALL!B3:K, 
            "SELECT * WHERE K CONTAINS 'FEE PENDING' "),



)))))))))))
```

i am looking QUERY AND DROPDOWN FILTER FORMULA IN GOOGLE SHEET. pl help me correct my google sheet file

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't write in caps the title of posts or comments but instead use normal casing. Also, you should try to post your questions as a [*"Minimal, Reproducible, Example."*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), meaning the code in the question should isolate a single problem and have no more code than the minimum necessary to reproduce the problem by copy-pasting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

added formula to your sheet. Please test it out.

formula in cell B5:

`=FILTER(ALL!B3:K,IFERROR(REGEXMATCH(ALL!D3:D,"^MP 0"&REGEXEXTRACT(A2,"\d")),REGEXMATCH(ALL!D3:D,"^MP")),REGEXMATCH(ALL!H3:H,IFS(NOT(ISERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A3,"ALL\s(.*?\s.*?)\s"))),REGEXEXTRACT(A3,"ALL\s(.*?\s.*?)\s"),REGEXMATCH(A3,"FEE"),"FEE",REGEXMATCH(A3,"^ALL APPLICATIONS"),"LICENSE|FEE")))`

-

[image]

Comment: @ACHU debugging question are generally welcome but phrasing comments or questions like [*"do it for me"*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274630) isn't generally well received on the site.